# How can return part of a string between two comma characters?

Tags: java

say I'm given a set of strings that looks like this:

```
0,test0,dummy
1,test,dummy
2,test1,dummy
3,test2,dummy
4,test3,dum,dum,dummy
```

I wrote code that can return only what's before the last ",":

```
public class RandomTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testFile = "synsets11.txt";
    In testIn = new In(testFile);
    while (testIn.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = testIn.readLine();
        String result = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(","));
        List<String> synList = Arrays.asList(result.split(","));
        for (String i : synList) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I intended to do was only return the part of the string that was between the first and second "," characters, so my code above doesn't work for the last line of text. How do I only return what's between the first and second comma?
In this case, only test0, test, test1, test2, and test3.

thanks!

Comment: How about just `split()`ing on comma and getting element 1?

Comment: @Biffen How would I do that? sorry, I'm new to string manipulation :p

Comment: See TheLostMind's answer.

Answer (score 6):

use `split()` method like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "0,prop,dummy";
    System.out.println(s.split(",")[1]);
}
```

O/P:

```
prop
```

NOTE : You have to check whether the String contains atleast 1 `,` (unless you want an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` :P)

Comment: As an alternative to checking whether the string contains a comma one could check that the result of `split()` has at least two elements.

Comment: @Nisekyuu- You might want to look into dasblinkennight's answer. His answer is very efficient

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `lastIndexOf`, use `indexOf` twice:

```
int pos = line.indexOf(',', line.indexOf(',')+1);
String result = line.substring(0, pos);
```

Comment: This is actually the most efficient answer here.. +1 :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)^[^,]*,|,.*", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK2oE3/2)

```
String s = "0,test0,dummy\n" + 
        "1,test,dummy\n" + 
        "2,test1,dummy\n" + 
        "3,test2,dummy\n" + 
        "4,test3,dum,dum,dummy";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^[^,]*,|,.*", ""));
```

Comment: That's too complicated for this task, better using `split`, way more readable IMO.

Comment: @MarounMaroun a single replace will do this job but splitting needs to split each line according to a newline character , i think.

Answer (score 0):

What about StringTokenizer?

```
public class RandomTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testFile = "synsets11.txt";
    In testIn = new In(testFile);
    StringTokenizer stok = null;
    while (testIn.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = testIn.readLine();
        stok = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

        for(int i = 0; i< stok.countTokens() ; i++){
             String str = st.nextToken();  
                if( i == 1){
                       System.out.println(str);
                   }else if( i > 1){break;}
            }// for
       }// while
   }//main
}//class
```